Why doesn't Wold's theorem guarantee a causal solution of an AR-system?
An AR-system $a(L)(x_t)=(\epsilon _t)$ has a unique stationary solution if and only if $a(L)$ is invertible i.e. the AR-polynomial has no roots on the unit circle. This solution is causal if and only if, additionally, it has no roots IN the unit circle. So an AR-system might have a unique stationary non-causal solution. Wold's theorem, on the other hand, guarantees that every weakly stationary process with mean $0$ (which holds true for every stationary solution of an AR-system) can be written as an $MA(\infty)$-process. How is this not a contradiction? What am I getting wrong here?
